# Spring MVC + Eclipse + Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-mvc, configuration

I know there are a lot of explanation about how to configure spring MVC with tomcat and eclipse.
Just wondering what I am missing. I've already check other solutions, but none help me out with this.

Here are the files I'm using:
1) web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

2) dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.controle.pronto" />
</beans:beans>
```

3) index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

4) HomeController.java
    package com.controle.pronto;

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
* Handles requests for the application home page.
*/
@Controller
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "home";
}
}
```

5) And here is my worskspace structure

```
src
    main
        webapp
            WEB-INF
                views
                    home.jsp
                dispatcher-servlet.xml
                web.xml
            index.jsp
```

When i try to access: 
- localhost:8080/controleponto
- localhost:8080/controleponto/index
- localhost:8080/controleponto/index.jsp
I get into 404 page - The requested resource is not available.

If you could provide me some feedback in what I'm doing wrong, I'll be thankful.

Thanks,
Luis Amaral

Comment: What about controller?

Comment: Check the context root of your application is `controleponto`. You can use tomcat manager to check this, or check Eclipse project properties. Also, how is configured your controller ?

Comment: Just updated with HomeController.java

Comment: I think your context name is wrong. The url you should be trying is  localhost:8080/<WEB_APP_NAME>

Comment: Do you have `/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml` in your project?

Comment: yes. I've just found the issue. I had renamed the src package name and for reason the properties was lost. I've just re-created the project and voile.. everything working. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your server.xml file. You will find your context root there. something like this

```
<Context docBase="yourApp" path="/yourApp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:yourApp"/></Host>
```

Try loading `localhost:8080/yourApp` assuming you are running tomcat on port 8080.

Comment: Yeah... I can see into server.xml:
    <Context docBase="controleponto" path="/controleponto" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:controleponto"/>

Comment: Maybe the issue is when starting tomcat.. I see this log:

Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:controleponto' did not find a matching property

Answer (score 0):

At first, the server will search for the index file. So, past your index.jsp file outside the webapp directory.

Also, try adding  in your dispatcher-servlet.xml.

Answer (score 0):

First try with local:8080 , If its running fine Then its means your Tomcat is working fine .

Than just put simple .html file just under web-app and right click on it run it as server  you can see its run in eclipse ,then you know the actual name your application using for your web application.

Than everything will run smoothly , I had faced this problem myself lots of time